# Replace many PNG files with specified one

Tags: linux

I'v got a lot of PNG files and directories with PNG files in one folder. How can I replace every file with specified one using Linux command?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're question is not 100% clear. Please provide an example of the desired output of the folder structure and files?

Comment: In directory / there are directories /a and /b . In /a there is A.png and B.png . In /b there is x.png and y.png . I would like to replace every png file with MMM.png. So after replacing every file in / will keep its name but content will change to MMM.png content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Notice:** Backup your files before you try this. The command below will overwrite the image files on your system.

Assuming you have a directory structure like this:

```
a
├── a.png
├── a1.png
├── a2.png
b
├── b.png
├── b2.png
├── b3.png
MMM.png
```

And want to replace ALL those png files in directories `/a` and `/b` with the contents of `MMM.png`. This command will find all the png files in those two directories and replace them with the contents of MMM.png.

```
find /a /b -name '*.png' -exec cp /MMM.jpg {}  \;
```

If you need to add more directories to the list (for example `/c` and `/d`), just separate them with a space.

```
find /a /b /c /d -name '*.png' -exec cp /MMM.jpg {}  \;
```